# "cordova run android" returns Command failed : apkanalyzer[...] 'sh' is not recognized as internal or external command[...]

Tags: android, cordova, window

I am trying to run a cordova application on android studio and I'm using Windows Powershell.
I'm just at the beginning of the project and try to run `cordova run android` after a successful `cordova platform add android` but I get this error:

```
[...]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 2s
48 actionable tasks: 48 up-to-date
Built the following apk(s):
        C:\Users\diall\TimeTracker\time_manager_mobile\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\diall\AppData\Local\Android\sdk (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=undefined (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\Users\diall\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
Command failed with exit code 1: apkanalyzer manifest target-sdk C:\Users\diall\TimeTracker\time_manager_mobile\platforms\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
'sh' n'est pas reconnu en tant que commande interne
ou externe, un programme executable ou un fichier de commandes.
Translated as : 'sh' command is unknown
```

And I think that's normal because I'm running on windows PowerShell but it even doesn't work when I'm on Git Bash (I use mingw64 and WSL2 too).

Can someone know how to do? Thanks in advance.

If it works I'd like to install an existing vue.js on it and change some things to get a functionning app.

Answer (score 8):

I just forgot to run the android emulator. I downloaded the emulator via android studio, and run it, the I rerun the command "npm run android". This resolved the problem

Comment: this was the solution, thanks a lot, been tweaking for more than a day xd

Answer (score 3):

This happens when there is neither emulator nor device attached, i.e. when the command

> adb devices

returns empty devices list.

Comment: If this was the error message I wouldn't be here